# angular ng-model has not work in select tags

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I am using `ng-model` on select tags, but those are  a part of works. The code is

```
<select ng-model="uptpm.point" ng-if="uptpm.leval.length>0" class="form-control text-center nopaddingleft nopaddingright" ng-change="setPoint(uptpm)">
  <option value="{{uptpml.value}}" ng-repeat="uptpml in uptpm.leval">{{uptpml.value}}</option>
</select>`
```

the view is

[the datas struct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsqEj.png).

[Display effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zijc2.png)

Comment: Can you show your angular controller code? Also explain what exactly is not working..

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended to use ngRepeat within select/option elements.

Take a look at https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Taken from angularjs docs:

> The ngOptions attribute can be used to dynamically generate a list of  elements for the  element using the array or object obtained by evaluating the ngOptions comprehension expression.

I have wrote an example below:

Angular:

```
$scope.uptpm = [
      {value: '0'},
      {value: '4'}
];
$scope.point = 2;
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="point" ng-options="i.value as (i.value) for i in uptpm">
  <option value="" selected>Please Select</option>
</select>
```

See this plunker for a working example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yl2ZynulIuk3ApG9jmTl

Comment: My code structure is the same as yours。 This problem only occurs in chrome, ie will not happen